# CROSS JOIN more than two tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have three tables, t1, t2 and t3. Table structure and values:

```
t1_id | t1_k1 | t1_val
------+-------+--------
1     | k1foo | t1foo
2     | k1bar | t1bar
3     | k1baz | t1baz

t2_id | t2_k1 | t2_k2 | t2_val
------+-------+-------+--------
1     | k1foo | k2foo | t2foo
2     | k1bar | k2bar | t2bar
3     | k1baz | k2baz | t2baz

t3_id | t3_k2 | t3_val
------+-------+--------
1     | k2foo | t3foo
2     | k2bar | t3bar
3     | k2baz | t3baz
```

So with normal SQL I can join t1 and t2 on t1_k1 = t2_k1 and t2 and t3 on t2_k2 = t3_k2, that is:

```
SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t3_val
FROM t1, t2, t3
WHERE t1_k1 = t2_k1 AND t2_k2 = t3_k2
```

To get

```
t1foo | t2foo | t3foo
t1bar | t2bar | t3bar
t1baz | t2baz | t3baz
```

Now I'm trying to get the same result with bigQuery SQL. From my understanding, using CROSS JOIN should work just like the comma in regular SQL, so I thought the following would work:

```
SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t3_val
FROM test.t1 CROSS JOIN test.t2 CROSS JOIN test.t3
WHERE t1_k1 = t2_k1 AND t2_k2 = t3_k2
```

But I get an error that "Field 't3_k2' not found on either side of the JOIN".
Adding parentheses like this:

```
SELECT SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t3_val
FROM ((test.t1 CROSS JOIN test.t2) CROSS JOIN test.t3)
WHERE t1_k1 = t2_k1 AND t2_k2 = t3_k2
```

gives a (frankly quite cryptic) syntax error 'Encountered "" at line 0, column 0.'
With just two tables CROSS JOIN works, but then it's no different from a normal JOIN.
I haven't found examples using CROSS JOIN on more than two tables. Is it possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Try below

```
SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t3_val 
FROM (
  SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t2_k2
  FROM test.t1 AS a 
  CROSS JOIN test.t2 AS b
  WHERE t1_k1 = t2_k1 
) AS c
CROSS JOIN test.t3 AS d
WHERE t2_k2 = t3_k2
```

Note: I think your example is just tailored to address your CROSS JOIN issue - but wanted to mention that if your example really represents your issue  - you do not need CROSS JOIN - rather you need [INNER] JOIN, as in below

```
SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t3_val
FROM (
  SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t2_k2
  FROM test.t1 AS a JOIN test.t2 AS b
  ON t1_k1 = t2_k1 
) AS c
JOIN test.t3 AS d ON t2_k2 = t3_k2
```

> Added runnable example for second query - to prove it works :o)

```
SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t3_val
FROM (
  SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t2_k2
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS t1_id, 'k1foo' AS t1_k1, 't1foo' AS t1_val),
    (SELECT 2 AS t1_id, 'k1bar' AS t1_k1, 't1bar' AS t1_val),
    (SELECT 3 AS t1_id, 'k1baz' AS t1_k1, 't1baz' AS t1_val)
  ) AS a 
  JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS t2_id, 'k1foo' AS t2_k1, 'k2foo' AS t2_k2, 't2foo' AS t2_val),
    (SELECT 2 AS t2_id, 'k1bar' AS t2_k1, 'k2bar' AS t2_k2, 't2bar' AS t2_val),
    (SELECT 3 AS t2_id, 'k1baz' AS t2_k1, 'k2baz' AS t2_k2, 't2baz' AS t2_val)
  ) AS b
  ON t1_k1 = t2_k1 
) as c
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT 1 AS t3_id, 'k2foo' AS t3_k2, 't3foo' AS t3_val),
  (SELECT 2 AS t3_id, 'k2bar' AS t3_k2, 't3bar' AS t3_val),
  (SELECT 3 AS t3_id, 'k2baz' AS t3_k2, 't3baz' AS t3_val)
) AS d
ON t2_k2 = t3_k2
```

Comment: Your second example doesn't work. I edited it to read "SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t3_val FROM..." and I get: "Field 't3_val' not found on either side of the JOIN".

Comment: It does work, but then it works with regular JOIN as well. So what's the point of having CROSS JOINs?

Comment: as i mentioned  - i DO NOT see any reason for you to use CROSS JOIN in your example! btw, fixed second query

Comment: asking just in case  - do you know difference between CROSS JOIN with WHERE vs. JOIN with ON? from what I see in your example  - you just don't need CROSS JOIN at all here

Comment: So, what's the difference between CROSS JOIN with WHERE and JOIN with ON? And why your second example doesn't work?

Comment: have you tried after i corrected initial copy-paste? it `definitelly works` for me. if it doesn't work for you  - show what exactly you are running, what error and provide schema of your data

Comment: added example for you to check

Comment: Yes, but you changed it. As written originally it didn't work.

Comment: Anyway, don't want to sound annoying but I still don't see what's the purpose of CROSS JOIN in bigQuery SQL if it cannot be used in practice on more than two tables.

Comment: of course - read few comments above  - as I mentioned  - that was copy-paste error :)

Comment: INNER JOIN returns matching records from two or more tables.
CROSS JOIN returns cartesian result. For example - tableA contains 10 record, tableB contains 20 records. using cross join the result will be 10 x 20 = 200 records. Hope you see the difference now

Comment: I knew it already, but I'm asking specifically about CROSS JOIN on more than two tables. No information seems to be available.

Comment: i thought your question was more practical about how to make your particular query work - which is what I answered. as of why cross join behaves this way - not sure even though have sime weak guess related to internal naming intermediate result during the execution. you might post new question where you are very explicitelly state your question so you have better chances to get right answer

Answer (score 0):

As Mikhail noticed in his answer, you don't need CROSS JOIN, regular JOIN works fine. Here is how to do it in one statement, without multilevel JOINs:

I used inline SELECT statements to provide data for t1, t2, t3:

```
SELECT t1_val, t2_val, t3.t3_val as t3_val
FROM (SELECT 1 as t1_id, "k1foo" as t1_k1, "t1foo" as t1_val) t1
JOIN (SELECT 1 as t2_id, "k1foo" as t2_k1, "k2foo" as t2_k2, "t2foo" as t2_val) t2
ON t1_k1 = t2_k1 
JOIN (SELECT 1 as t3_id, "k2foo" as t3_k2, "t3foo" as t3_val) t3
ON t2_k2 = t3_k2
```

Comment: Thanks. So when is CROSS JOIN useful?

Comment: CROSS JOIN is needed when you don't have equality match between tables, but have some more complex condition instead. Then your only option is to do CROSS JOIN with WHERE clause. It might be much slower. When possible, use regular JOINs.

What does not work in this query for you? It does run successfully in BQ UI :).

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it's all a matter of defining table aliases, see the other question for an example: [CROSS JOIN: only two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527389/cross-join-only-two-tables/37548172).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it changed in the last 6 years, but now using commas as a CROSS JOIN works, you only need to be careful with ambiguity.

```
SELECT 
  t1_val, 
  t2_val, 
  t3_val
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT 1 AS t1_id, 'k1foo' AS t1_k1, 't1foo' AS t1_val) UNION ALL
  (SELECT 2 AS t1_id, 'k1bar' AS t1_k1, 't1bar' AS t1_val) UNION ALL
  (SELECT 3 AS t1_id, 'k1baz' AS t1_k1, 't1baz' AS t1_val)
) AS a
,(
  SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT 1 AS t2_id, 'k1foo' AS t2_k1, 'k2foo' AS t2_k2, 't2foo' AS t2_val) UNION ALL
  (SELECT 2 AS t2_id, 'k1bar' AS t2_k1, 'k2bar' AS t2_k2, 't2bar' AS t2_val) UNION ALL
  (SELECT 3 AS t2_id, 'k1baz' AS t2_k1, 'k2baz' AS t2_k2, 't2baz' AS t2_val)
) AS b
,(
  SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT 1 AS t3_id, 'k2foo' AS t3_k2, 't3foo' AS t3_val) UNION ALL
  (SELECT 2 AS t3_id, 'k2bar' AS t3_k2, 't3bar' AS t3_val) UNION ALL
  (SELECT 3 AS t3_id, 'k2baz' AS t3_k2, 't3baz' AS t3_val)
) AS c
where
  a.t1_k1 = b.t2_k1 
  AND b.t2_k2 = c.t3_k2
```

The above query results in:

```
t1foo | t2foo | t3foo
t1bar | t2bar | t3bar
t1baz | t2baz | t3baz
```

You can copy and paste to check.

---

But, yes, in this specific example it would be better to use a INNER JOIN as Michael and Mikhail pointed out.