# CROSS JOIN: only two tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

There does not seem to be documentation on whether CROSS JOIN in bigQuery SQL can be used on more than two tables.

If it's possible, I'd like to see the right syntax. If it's not possible, then it would be nice to know what is CROSS JOIN useful for, since with two tables regular JOINs can be used already.

See also this question: [CROSS JOIN more than two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484684/cross-join-more-than-two-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Cross join between 3 tables seem to work for me. See example below.

I use cross joins in some special situations where I deliberately want to duplicate rows. Or when you want to know all possible combinations between 2 tables, perhaps because another join would eliminate rows while you don't want that.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      'a' ),
    (
    SELECT
      'b' ),
    (
    SELECT
      'c' ) ) AS X1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      '1' ),
    (
    SELECT
      '2' ),
    (
    SELECT
      '3' ) ) AS X2
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      'x' ),
    (
    SELECT
      'y' ),
    (
    SELECT
      'z' ) ) AS X3
```

Comment: You have no WHERE clauses. Does it work with real tables and WHERE clauses to do the joins (see my other question for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484684/cross-join-more-than-two-tables)?

Comment: Yes that seems to work too ... I does require me to give every field a proper alias and select them by referring to both the table and field alias in the outer select. But that's standard BigQuery syntax quirks :)

Comment: Interesting, let me try that one.

Comment: Ok, so it does work using table aliases. I wasn't aware of this specific quirk. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably worth reading up on the various types of SQL joins: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL). They all serve a different purpose.

That said, as with every other type of join, you specify them pairwise but they can be chained together in a single from clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM a CROSS JOIN b CROSS JOIN c;
```

Comment: No they can't, that's why I asked (see my other question). And I know about the different types of join.

Comment: I know for certain that they can because I was the one who wrote that code. I just verified it now by running

SELECT count(*)
FROM
  (select * from [bigquery-public-data:samples.trigrams] limit 10) a
  cross join
  (select * from [bigquery-public-data:samples.trigrams] limit 10) b
  cross join
  (select * from [bigquery-public-data:samples.trigrams] limit 10) c;

Answer (score 0):

So for the benefit of whoever might read this: the problem is that bigQuery SQL makes it more or less mandatory to use table (and field) aliases, so for example a working CROSS JOIN on three tables might be:

```
SELECT tt1.t1_val, tt2.t2_val, tt3.t3_val FROM
test.t1 AS tt1 CROSS JOIN test.t2 as tt2 CROSS JOIN test.t3 AS tt3
WHERE tt1.t1_k1 = tt2.t2_k1 AND tt2.t2_k2 = tt3.t3_k2
```